# How to change Indian rupees currency in Magento 1.9.2?

Tags: magento-1.9

How to change Indian rupees currency in Magento 1.9.2?

I want Indian currency for my website in magento but coming not any idea for this.

Answer (score 2):

First GOTO 
Admin->System->Configuration->Currency Setup-> Change Indian Rupee Next Goto
Go to lib\Zend\Locale\Data\root.xml line no 3550
Find

```
<currency type="INR">
    <symbol>₹</symbol>
    <symbol alt="narrow">₹</symbol>
</currency>
```

to Replace below code

```
<currency type="INR">
    <symbol>र</symbol>
    <symbol alt="narrow">र</symbol>
</currency>
```

Comment: i am using magento 2.0.7 
vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Locale\Data\root.xml
i replaced the above code and also refreshed cache but i could not find any changes in my currency symbol